# Disabling a button when a form is loaded and enabling when the form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable a button (`button3`) on a primary form when a second, modeless form (`Form2`) is loaded, and then re-enable the button when the modeless form is closed.

Here is what I've tried:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 p = new Form2(label1.Text);
    p.Show();

    if (p.Shown)
        this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
    else
        this.button3.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
}
```

Comment: button3.Enabled = false ; should work if it is the same form?!

Comment: yeah but button3 is in form1. I want to load form2 then dissable button 3 and then when i close from2 i want to ennable button3 in form1 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method for achieving this would be to disable `button3` prior to showing `Form2`, and using the `FormClosed` event on `Form2` to re-enable `button3` once the form is closed:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ...

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Instantiate the form and assign the FormClosed event
        var form = new Form2(label1.Text);
        form.FormClosed += Form2_FormClosed;

        // Disable button3
        button3.Enabled = false;

        // Show the form
        form.Show();
    }

    // Occurs when Form2 is closed
    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Re-enable button3
        button3.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

An alternative method, that assigns a lambda expression to the `FormClosed` event:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Instantiate the form
    var form = new Form2(label1.Text);

    // Assign a lambda method to the FormClosed event to re-enable button3
    form.FormClosed += (s, a) => button3.Enabled = true;

    // Disable button3
    button3.Enabled = false;

    // Show the form
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: well the button3 is in Form1

Comment: I updated the answer to make clear that the methods describe above are in `Form1`. No code needs to be added to `Form2`.

Comment: Not working.. 

var form = new Form2();

Form2 underlines in a red color..

Comment: Try now. You were passing label1.Text to the form. I added this to the example.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing, i m not sure to understand what you want to do but maybe it will help you.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{ 
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button3.Enabled = false;
    Form2 p = new Form2(label1.Text);

    p.ShowDialog();


    //the code will stop here until you finish your work on form2

     Button3.Enabled=true;
}
```

it works with me.

But if your form3 is just a short label use:

```
Button3.Enabled= false;
MessageBox.show ("blabla");
Button3.Enabled=true;
```

Comment: By making the second form a modal dialog, you've effectively eliminated the need to disable the button, as it can not be interacted with until the second form is closed. I believe the question is asking specifically about the case of a modeless dialog.

Comment: valid the answer then :)